# 2 Google Tag Manager containers = double triggers?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Joomla website with existing analytics done by a GTM tag and I need to add another image tag (1x1 pixel) from a separate GTM container. I set the event name for the additional GTM container to a different name from from the existing GTM container (default 'gtm.js') so that the new tag only fires under the specified event. The new container tested out fine in a blank HTML page, but when it is put in the website, it ends up firing twice. I know that because Firebug showed 2 1x1 pixels being loaded and I mark each request with a randomly-generated UID to distinguish them on the server side.

I suspect this being caused by having multiple GTM container tags but want to check whether anyone has run into this problem before? As of now, I could not verify nor fix the double counting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can verify that having multiple containers on the same site causes tags to fire twice. I have found no documentation to support the use of two containers from the Google Tag Manager dev docs. As of now, this appears to be a limitation of GTM.

Comment: Thanks. This only means that when a client is already using GTM and refuses to hand over access, we just have tell them to half the numbers :D.

Answer (score 5):

Well actually you can do this by changing the data layer name - see [this](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#renaming):

> It is possible to implement multiple containers on the same page. By
>   default, each container will use a common data layer. If you'd like
>   each container to use its own data layer, you may modify the data
>   layer name in one or more of your container snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement GTM with the same data layer name. I recommend using [Google tag assistant for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en).